# SQL Server SELECT into existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to select some fields from one table and insert them into an existing table from a stored procedure. Here is what I am trying:

```
SELECT col1, col2
INTO dbo.TableTwo 
FROM dbo.TableOne 
WHERE col3 LIKE @search_key
```

I think `SELECT ... INTO ...` is for temporary tables which is why I get an error that `dbo.TableTwo` already exists.

How can I insert multiple rows from `dbo.TableOne` into `dbo.TableTwo`?

Comment: Since you've already accepted an answer, I wanted to offer just a note: Select Into  isn't "for temporary tables", it is for creating a new table based on the structure (and data) of the select portion of the query.  For a table X, you can only ever Select Into it a maximum of 1 time*, after that you need to use Insert Into to append any data.  *If the table exists already, then zero times. This is of course unless you DROP the table first.

Comment: but do note that Select Into doesn't copy index / primary key / foreign key constraints, so it leaves you with an unindexed heap-o-data.  It's useful for quick dev work, but not the way to add / move a real production table.

Comment: just run this statement 'drop table tabletwo;' and run above query. Select ...into isn't for temporary tables.

Comment: The syntax to create a new table (here `destination`) is `SELECT   select_list  INTO  destination FROM source [WHERE condition]`. The `select_list` can be certain columns but the `*` can also be used.

Answer (score 746, accepted):

`SELECT ... INTO ...` only works if the table specified in the INTO clause does not exist - otherwise, you have to use:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TABLETWO
SELECT col1, col2
  FROM dbo.TABLEONE
 WHERE col3 LIKE @search_key
```

This assumes there's only two columns in dbo.TABLETWO - you need to specify the columns otherwise:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TABLETWO
  (col1, col2)
SELECT col1, col2
  FROM dbo.TABLEONE
 WHERE col3 LIKE @search_key
```

Comment: It is a best practice to always specify the columns no matter if they are all there or not. It will help prevent things from breaking when someone adds a column.

Comment: Hmm, the `SELECT... INTO...` statement doesn't seem to work if the table specified in the `INTO` clause does not already exist. I am getting an "undeclared variable" error. Though maybe this issue is only for MySQL. The `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE .. worked`;

Comment: @Gnuey SELECT ... INTO ... only works if there is an existing table.  If there isn't an existing table, use the original poster's format (that'll create a new table)

Comment: @Will Did you mean the opposite of what you said? ´SELECT ... INTO ...´ requires a non-existing table to be specified, while ´INSERT INTO ...´ requires an existing table to be specified.

Comment: @AndréChristofferAndersen Doh, you're correct.  My apologies, I must not have double checked before I commented.  I wonder if I should delete my comment so it doesn't confuse others?

Comment: Both of these operations are pretty fast.  I just did 2M rows on a 20 col table in less than 2 mins.  YMMV of course.  Way faster than ETL.

Comment: I wish there was a counter for the number of times I check back and use this answer!

Answer (score 37):

There are two different ways to implement inserting data from one table to another table.

### For Existing Table - INSERT INTO SELECT

This method is used when the table is already created in the database earlier and the data is to be inserted into this table from another table. If columns listed in insert clause and select clause are same, they are not required to list them. It is good practice to always list them for readability and scalability purpose.

```
----Create testable
CREATE TABLE TestTable (FirstName VARCHAR(100), LastName VARCHAR(100))
----INSERT INTO TestTable using SELECT
INSERT INTO TestTable (FirstName, LastName)
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Person.Contact
WHERE EmailPromotion = 2
----Verify that Data in TestTable
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM TestTable
----Clean Up Database
DROP TABLE TestTable
```

### For Non-Existing Table - SELECT INTO

This method is used when the table is not created earlier and needs to be created when data from one table is to be inserted into the newly created table from another table. The new table is created with the same data types as selected columns.

```
----Create a new table and insert into table using SELECT INSERT
SELECT FirstName, LastName
INTO TestTable
FROM Person.Contact
WHERE EmailPromotion = 2
----Verify that Data in TestTable
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM TestTable
----Clean Up Database
DROP TABLE TestTable
```

Ref [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688281/select-into-table-will-it-work-for-inserting-data-into-existing-table?noredirect=1&lq=1) [2](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/15/sql-server-insert-data-from-one-table-to-another-table/)

Answer (score 5):

It would work as given below :

```
insert into Gengl_Del Select Tdate,DocNo,Book,GlCode,OpGlcode,Amt,Narration 
from Gengl where BOOK='" & lblBook.Caption & "' AND DocNO=" & txtVno.Text & ""
```

Comment: +1 to counteract the -1 and for the effort giving ideas that can be used or be referenced by other users. @MarkSowul is right of SQL injection but for the sake of academic purposes other people can try that kind of method.

Comment: Most tables have an auto increment field, which can't be inserted. So `SELECT *` won't work. This is a better way, thanks!

Comment: @User6675636b20796f7521 I would not go so far as to suggesting it's "okay" for other people to try that kind of method, if it's the SQL injection we're talking about. It should never be done, and thus never be tried. It would be far more productive to edit this answer showing the *correct* way to do this from the very beginning, and if anyone asks, "what's with the question marks/at symbols?" you simply reply, "those are parameter markers for use in parameterized queries (out of scope)" and let them figure it out from there.

Answer (score 4):

If the destination table **does exist** but you don't want to specify column names:

```
DECLARE @COLUMN_LIST NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SQL_INSERT NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @COLUMN_LIST = (SELECT DISTINCT
    SUBSTRING(
        (
            SELECT ', table1.' + SYSCOL1.name  AS [text()]
            FROM sys.columns SYSCOL1
            WHERE SYSCOL1.object_id = SYSCOL2.object_id and SYSCOL1.is_identity <> 1
            ORDER BY SYSCOL1.object_id
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000)
FROM
    sys.columns SYSCOL2
WHERE
    SYSCOL2.object_id = object_id('dbo.TableOne') )

SET @SQL_INSERT =  'INSERT INTO dbo.TableTwo SELECT ' + @COLUMN_LIST + ' FROM dbo.TableOne table1 WHERE col3 LIKE ' + @search_key
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL_INSERT
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you want a identity column in new table created with select into then it can be done as below.

```
SELECT 
 ID = IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1),
        name
INTO    table2
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

This *does not* work on MS SQL Server, but will work on Sybase.

```
select *
into existing table database..existingtable
from database..othertables....
```

If you have used `select * into tablename from other tablenames` already, next time, to append, you say `select * into existing table tablename from other tablenames`

Comment: PS Tested on SYBASE ASE 15.5

Comment: The OP is asking for MS SQL.

Comment: Please remove, this is confusing/noise as this isn't SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert into Table_A, from Table_B, only if the column is not in Table_A, then use the following:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO dbo.Table_A (Column_1)
SELECT DISTINCT Some_Column AS Column_1
FROM dbo.Table_B 
WHERE Some_Column 
    NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT GroupId 
            FROM dbo.Table_A)

COMMIT
```