# Can select statement updates data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I just got hand over with hundreds of SQL views, stored procedures and functions
I like to see data visually to better understand what the object does.

Can I assume if I run a select statement and execute the query - there is no chance that it modifies record/data?

I am just worry that there are some SQL tricks that can updates data via select statement.

Anything to watch out for inside the select? Any tips or keyword that I have to look out for?

Comment: if anything doesnt make sense just EXECUTE sp_helptext 'ObjectName' will give you the definition of that object see inside whats going on. Nothing to worry about Views but I would suggest to see Stored Procs and Function Definitions before you touch them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal, basic `SELECT` does not modify data.  However, there are a few things you should keep an eye out for.

If the code uses dynamic SQL to build a SELECT statement, you must worry about a [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack.  Unless you are careful about parameterizing dynamic SQL, an attacker can do pretty much anything that the current login can do.  For example, `DROP TABLE`, `DROP DATABASE`, etc.  See the linked article on Wikipedia.

Furthermore, beware that a `SELECT` with the `INTO` clause can be used to create a table and insert records into it.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101739/sql-server-select-into-existing-table) and [Microsoft TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx) for more information.

Comment: how does that answer his question. He said nothing in the question about SQL Injection Attack.

Comment: The OP asked if there were SQL tricks that can cause a `SELECT` statement to update data.  I would say a SQL Injection attack definitely qualifies as a "trick" that someone can use to force a dynamic SQL `SELECT` statement to change data.  Also, note that I edited my answer to mention SELECT INTO.

Comment: +1 for remembering the SELECT INTO! Thanks for updating your answer.

Answer (score 2):

A Plain old `SELECT` statement by itself won't update any data.

Even if the `SELECT` statements has calls into 1 or more `FUNCTION`s, you can rest assured that none of those `FUNCTION`s will be modifying any data in your `DATABASE`**

** See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx 
The 1st limitation of Functions listed is

> User-defined functions cannot be used to perform actions that modify
>   the database state.

I even tried writing a `FUNCTION` that did an `INSERT` before returning a return value, and the error I got was as follows. [Thanks to @Aaron and @John for keeping me honest].

```
Msg 443, Level 16, State 15, Procedure CRUDFunction, Line 5
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT' within a function.
```

Comment: A function can't perform side effects, so unless they are doing something crazy like [looping back via `xp_cmdshell`](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/denis_gobo/archive/2008/05/08/6703.aspx)...

Comment: thanks for reminding functions. Looks like there are only 20 - 30 functions and they all labelled accordingly.