# Inserting multiple rows into some table using values from select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

It is possible to insert multiple rows in one table using values from select statement?
an example:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable (UserID, ModuleID, ModuleRights) VALUES 
      (u.UserId, 1, 15),
      (u.UserId, 2, 1),
      (u.UserId, 4, 3),
      (u.UserId, 8, 7)
SELECT * FROM Users u
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server SELECT into existing table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101739/sql-server-select-into-existing-table)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but you need to be careful how you do it.  In this case, it appears you want a `cross join`:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable (UserID, ModuleID, ModuleRights)
    SELECT u.UserId, v.ModuleID, v.ModuleRights
    FROM Users u CROSS JOIN
         (VALUES (1, 15), 
                 (2, 1), 
                 (4, 3), 
                 (8, 7)
         ) v(ModuleID, ModuleRights);
```

Comment: Best answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable (UserID, ModuleID, ModuleRights) 
SELECT u.UserID, u.ModuleID, u.ModuleRights FROM Users u;
```

If your `ModuleID` and `ModuleRights` are not part of the `users` table then insert nulls or dummy values and replace on needed condition.

Answer (score -1):

insert multiple rows using select statment

```
insert into tbl_teacher
    (fName,
    lName,
    email,
    cNo)
    select s.fName,
           s.lName,
           s.email,
           s.cNo 
    from tbl_student s
```

Comment: Downvoted because this is too similar to vtuhtan's answer which was submitted 16 minutes earlier.  The answer is also poorly formatted, but I wouldn't downvote for that.