# Adding rows of one table to rows of another table where two tables are matched by ID

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

In an Access 2013 database, I have a table t1 and another table t2. They both have the same number of columns and column names are also the same. Table t2 have a number of overlaps with id variable of table t1. I am trying to make a new table t3 where I ***add all the rows of t1 and only those rows of t2 that are not matched by an id variable present in both*** the tables t1 and t2. I used something like

```
Create Table t3 As Select * From (Select t1.* From t1 Inner Join t2 on t1.ID_Number = t2. ID_Number)
```

This throws syntax error. However, even if it worked this will select those rows that matches ID_Number in both the tables. I have tried various other codes and browsed through many other relevant stackoverflow post but could not resolve it.

Comment: I have also used UNION ALL but this doesn't give the right answer as it copies the overlapping variables also.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT t1.*
INTO t3
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.ID_Number = t2.ID_Number
```

Comment: Thanks. But sorry that I asked it in a wrong way. Actually, I want to select those rows from t2 whose ID does not match with t1. How can I do that? Again, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Do you want insert dont match data to table t3? Did I understand right

Comment: Yes. All rows of t1 and only those rows of t2 that don't match by id. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: change this :
ON t1.ID_Number <> t2.ID_Number

Comment: Doesn't work. Creates the same observation a couple of times. Again, if we are putting <> in INNER JOIN it is not even an inner join at all. t1 have 140 observations, t2 has 147 observations, but after I use INNER JOIn with <> I get t3 with 20578 observations!!!! However, I know that there are only 5 to 7 overlaps. So, excluding those overlaps I am expecting the result to be a table of around 282 to 287 observations.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Access syntax but can this 2-step solution work?

```
select t1.* into t3 from t1 where t1.ID_Number not in (select t2.ID_Number from t2)

select t2.* into t3 from t2 where t2.ID_Number not in (select t1.ID_Number from t1)
```

Comment: When I try to run the second line, I get an error: "The existing table t3 will be deleted before you run the query"

Comment: OK then see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4101761/881375 and change second statement