# Insert a derived table in SQL into a newly created table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables(Current and Prior) that have all the same columns and are combined through a full outer join in a query. I also have a derived column for each of the respective columns that compares the values of Current and Prior corresponding fields and says whether they match or not. This creates a derived table that has all the Current and Prior Fields as well as a derived comparing column. I need to create an actual table in a database that captures that data. How would I do that?

Comment: `SELECT ... INTO NewTableName FROM ...`?  You could also create the table in advance and just do an `INSERT NewTableName (columns...) SELECT ...`

Comment: This sounds like a good idea for a *view* versus a table, though.

Comment: [Insert into a table you created](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4101761/6167855) and using [select into a new table (created on the fly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683758/how-to-create-a-table-from-select-query-result-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: I would use a proc that does your selects from both tables and the comparing column into a temp table then select from it. Easier to manage and less memory.

Comment: what is a proc? also i tried just doing select ... into and it doesnt actually for some reason carry over the values i am trying to insert

Comment: actually select into worked

Comment: a proc is a [procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql), often referred to as a [stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure) but it is not needed contrary to @briskovich suggestions since your desire (for better or worse) is to have an actual table. Otherwise, i'd just [create a view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views) from your query which is a *virtual* table and thus doesn't take much space (unless indexed)

Answer (score 0):

This should create a view for you to use, in case the tables are not very large.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_Compare]
AS
SELECT /* Column list*/
    IIF(A.Col1 IS NULL, 1, 0) AS [CompareCol1],
    IIF(A.Col2 IS NULL, 1, 0) AS [CompareCol2]
FROM A
FULL OUTER JOIN C
    ON A.Col1 = C.Col1
```

If you wish to create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Compare]
(
    [CompareCol1] BIT,
    [CompareCol2] BIT,
    /* Insert Column 1 to N here */
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Compare]
(
    [CompareCol1],
    [CompareCol2],
    /* Column list*/
)
SELECT IIF(A.Col1 IS NULL, 1, 0) AS [CompareCol1],
    IIF(A.Col2 IS NULL, 1, 0) AS [CompareCol2],
    /* Column list*/
FROM A
FULL OUTER JOIN C
    ON A.Col1 = C.Col1
```