# Merging two small tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

```
Auth: sessionId | deviceId
Tokens: token | sessionId
```

(**sessionId** in tables **auth** and **token** are associated)

What I want to have: only one table **Auth** with colums **sessionId, deviceId, token**.

I don't know how to move column with its data from second table to first.

Comment: You might want to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101739/sql-server-select-into-existing-table

Comment: You wants new column to add in the Auth table? or you want get results from both table in a single query output? also please tag proper database name.

Comment: @mkRabbani, I need add new column to table 'Auth' and paste there data fron table 'Tokens', then I need to delete table 'Tokens'

Comment: @computercarguy, this is not my case. I need to insert Tokens.token to Auth.token, where Tokens.sessionId is equeal Auth.sessionId

Comment: Ok. With the clarification you gave, try looking at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match

Answer (score 0):

This following steps is workable for MySQL and SQL Server-

1.Add new column "Token" to the table "Auth"

```
ALTER TABLE Auth
ADD Token datatype -- Define the datatype
```

2.Update new column in Auth table using this following query-

```
UPDATE Auth
SET Auth.Token = Token.Token
FROM Auth
INNER JOIN Token
    ON Auth.sessionId = Token.sessionId
```

3.Remove the table "Token"

Comment: this is non-standard SQL. Please mention for which DBMS product this works

Comment: Mentioned... Thanks.